# How do I create a Git Repository within a TeamProject in Tfs?

Tags: c#, git, tfs, tfvc, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to move a TfsServer from an old TFVC based Server (2013), to a newer version (2018). I got most of it figured out but I just can't manage to create a lot of repositories programmatically.

I've been trying to use Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ExtendedClient to create the repositories in a specific TeamProject, based on a list of names. I've managed to query all the repositories that already exist:

```
public void CreateTeamProjectRepositories(IEnumerable<string> input)
{
      using (var newCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(_newUrl)))
      {
           var service = newCollection.GetService<GitRepositoryService>();
      }
}
```

Sadly the documentation is fairly thin on this, in fact the only kind of official documentation I was able to find is this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/dn231953(v%3Dvs.120)

I can't even find that class in the Extended Client, the only class I Can find is `GitRepositoryService` that I used above but there seems to be no documentation whatsoever for that class.

I found some unofficial stuff online describing how to create TeamProjects, but nothing on Repos within a TeamProject (remote url like www.url.com:8080/tfs/TeamProjectCollection/TeamProject/_git/RepoName).

Anyone got some experience with this?

Comment: Are you trying to create the repositories on the 2013 instance, or the 2018 instance?

Comment: I'm trying it in the 2018 instance. We have a huge workspace with tons of projects in it and I want to get some structure into it. I'm using git-tfs to convert the TFVC Branches into local Git repos but there's so many that creating them all manually would be a lot of effort and I was hoping there's some way to do it programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can create a Git repository with the old TFS classes but you can do it with the new TFS [.Net libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries) (available in NuGet):

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/{collection}"), new VssCredentials());
GitHttpClient gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
GitRepository newRepo = new GitRepository() { Name = "newRepo" };
await gitClient.CreateRepositoryAsync(newRepo, "teamProjectName");
```

The above code work on TFS 2018, if you want to create the repositories in TFS 2013 I'm not sure the code will work, so you can use `HttpClient` to execute the Rest API and create the repo:

```
var tfsUrl = "http://tfstest01:8080/tfs/{collection}";
var tfsUri = new Uri(tfsInstance + "/{teamProjectGUID}/_apis/git/repositories/?api-version=1.0");
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
{
     var data = new { name = "newRepo" };
     var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
     var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
     HttpResponseMessage response = null;
     response = client.PostAsync(tfsUri, content).Result;
}
```

Comment: @Vaethin I also updated the answer with `HttpClient` example :)